# SSA Copy Folding

Tags: optimization, compilers, static-analysis

When can we fold copies in SSA?

We are clearly allowed to fold a copy such as

```
a0 = call foo()
b0 = a0
```

But what about a program such as

```
a0 = call foo()
C0 = call bar() // ignore sinking briefly, assume this is used later
if(a0) {
    a1 = C0
}
a2 = phi(a0, a1)
call print(a2)
```

We can't fold the `a1 = C0` copy because `phi(a0, C0)` would have altered meaning: both its parameters dominate the phi node and it will always evaluate to `C0`.

**Two more cases:**

```
a0 = call foo();
a1 = call bar();
do {
    a2 = phi(a0, t0)
    call print(a2)
    t0 = a1
} while(...)
```

Can't fold the `t0 = a1` copy for the same reason as the first case (it would become dominated by both parameters).

```
x0 = call foo()
C0 = call bar() // constant / loop invariant
do {
    a0 = C0
    if(x0) {
        a1 = call baz()
    }
    a2 = phi(a0, a1)
    call print(a2)
} while(...)
```

Can't fold the `a0 = C0` copy here because that makes the phi node (which becomes `phi(C0, a1)`) invalid across loop iterations. As soon as the x0 branch is taken, the `phi(C0, a1)` phi node can never evaluate to `C0` in subsequent iterations.

**Restrictions:** I have a couple restrictions in my IR which may help the analysis:

1. All loops are canonicalized into do-while loops so I can assume they run at least once
2. The CFG is reducible and a phi node will always have two parameters

**What I've tried:**
Here's the logic I've been able to come up with currently: Cannot fold a copy if

- The copy (let's call it `a = b`) has a phi node dependant and `a` does not dominate the phi but `b` does.
- Or the copy is in the same loop as one of its phi node dependants and the replacement (`b`) dominates the phi.

**Question:**
My question boils down to

- How can I improve this logic
- How can I better encapsulate the third case / generalize
- Or, am I attempting to solve the wrong problem here?